# Create Grid. Insert Points to Grid

Tags: python, insert, grid, points

I got a * .txt file with xyz coordinates. I importet the data and create three lists for x,y and z. 
Now I want to generate a grid over all Points with a gridcell for example by 1x1 m. I want to get, the lowest z-value in each of the cells und generate a Digital Elevation Model (DEM) of this z-values. I do this before in the software Arcmap (see picture). Because of the huge number of Points (over 20 Million) its take very long .The Process step by step:
1.  Import data an get a list of x,y,z (allready done)
2.  Create grids over the Points (for example 1x1 m)
3.  Intersect the grid with Points
4.  Get the lowest z-value of every cell
5.  Generate a DEM of the lowest z-value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVKG3.png)

Comment: How is your grid represented, and you mention *a* grid with 100 cells, but you want to know which points are in which grid as if there's more than one grid. Could you clarify (preferably with some code)?

Comment: I got a * .txt file with xyz coordinates. I importet the data and create three lists for x,y and z. Now I want to generate a grid over all Points with a gridcell for example by 1x1 m. I want to get, the lowest z-value in each of the cells und generate a Digital Elevation Model (DEM) of this z-values. I do this before in the software Arcmap (see picture). Because of the huge number of Points (over 20 Million) its take very long .

Comment: The Process step by step:
1. Import data an get a list of x,y,z (allready done)
2. Create grids over the Points (for example 1x1 m)
3. Intersect the grid with Points
4. Get the lowest z-value of every cell
5. Generate a DEM of the lowest z-value

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `np.meshgrid` function?

```
x_ = np.linspace(0., 1., 10)
y_ = np.linspace(1., 2., 20)
z_ = np.linspace(3., 4., 30)

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(x_, y_, z_, indexing='ij')
```

There are example numbers you can create your own grid